# OpenGl: Get distance information using z-buffer

Tags: opengl, distance, depth

I'd like to know how to get distance information from z-buffer (or depth buffer) in this way: based on my viewpoint I'd like to extract the distance as a 3x3 distance matrix of the objects in front of the viewplane. Is it possible?

Also is it possible to get the same information from another cop even if I am rendering in a completely different cop?

Comment: When you say "3x3 distance matrix" do you mean the transformation matrix? The depth buffer will hold a depth map once rendering is done (usually), not a 3x3 matrix.

Comment: What is a *"3x3 distance matrix"* and what is a *"cop"*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get information from the depth buffer other way that it is stored in it - as a depth value for each destination buffer (screen) pixel. If you'd like to calculate the distance to other objects from a given point, you could extract the data and reload it into another shader (or just to CPU-available array in memory), calculating the lenghts.

Comment: Although you could do a reverse projection.

Comment: maybe i expressed my self wrong. what i wanted to obtain is something like this matrix http://resumbrae.com/ub/dms423_f06/10/depthBuffer2.png

Comment: So exactly what you want is values from given area of depth buffer?

Comment: ... should've said it in the first place. [Relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164952/efficient-way-of-reading-depth-values-from-depth-buffer). In general, you can use `glReadPixels`